# Windows Update, Group Policy, wrong times

Tags: group-policy, windows-update

I have set a group policy to control when Windows Updates take place:
[image: group policy settings screenshot]

Note that we do not have a WSUS server.

Note also that our servers are in three separate timezones. The machines are organized into Active Directory OUs, and a separate group policy makes sure that the timezone setting for each machine is correct.

My intent, as the policy settings say, is to have each machine do windows updates and reboot, starting at 12 midnight **local** time, on Sundays only.

Instead, my machines have started installing windows updates whenever they wish. I just had a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM reboot in the middle of the day. This machine is in timezone CDT; it was about 12:30 PM (afternoon, not early morning) on Thursday when it rebooted.  Another machine in CEST (Amsterdam) rebooted at **my** local time 12:10 AM, its local time 6:10 AM.  On Thursday.

What have I done wrong?

Can I obtain my goal without installing a WSUS server?

EDIT: RSOP and Eventlog proof.

AMS machine RSOP:

```
RSOP data for **REDACTED**\rpresser on **REDACTED** : Logging Mode
-------------------------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Member Server
OS Version:                  6.3.9600
Site Name:                   AMS1
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\rpresser
Connected over a slow link?: No


COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------
    CN=**REDACTED**
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 10/27/2016 at 7:43:57 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      **REDACTED**
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        **REDACTED**
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2008 or later

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Default Domain Policy
        Local time & time servers - AMS
        Windows Update settings

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    The computer is a part of the following security groups
    -------------------------------------------------------
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        Everyone
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        This Organization
        **REDACTED**$
        Domain Computers
        Authentication authority asserted identity
        System Mandatory Level
```

AMS machine Eventlog entry:

```
Information 10/27/2016 5:54:12 AM   User32  1074    None
The process C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe (**REDACTED**) has initiated the restart of computer **REDACTED** on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Recovery (Planned)
 Reason Code: 0x80020002
 Shutdown Type: restart
 Comment:
```

CHI machine RSOP:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0
c 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Created on 10/27/2016 at 2:14:41 PM


RSOP data for **REDACTED**\rpresser on **REDACTED** : Logging Mode
--------------------------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Member Server
OS Version:                  6.3.9600
Site Name:                   CHI3
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\rpresser
Connected over a slow link?: No


COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------
    CN=**REDACTED**
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 10/27/2016 at 12:38:09 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      **REDACTED**
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        **REDACTED**
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2008 or later

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Default Domain Policy
        Local time & time servers - CHI
        Windows Update settings

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    The computer is a part of the following security groups
    -------------------------------------------------------
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        Everyone
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        This Organization
        Domain Computers
        System Mandatory Level
        **REDACTED**
```

CHI machine eventlog entry

```
Information 10/27/2016 12:19:50 PM  User32  1074    None
The process C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe (**REDACTED**) has initiated the restart of computer **REDACTED** on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Recovery (Planned)
 Reason Code: 0x80020002
 Shutdown Type: restart
 Comment:
```

Comment: You may have already done this, but you did not mention here in the post. What steps did you take to determine WSUS was the cause of the reboot? Could have been something besides Windows Update. A few things you should check: (1) Verify the GPO these settings reside in is being applied: `gpresult /r /scope computer` (2) Review SETUP event log to see when/if updates were applied. (3) Review SYSTEM event log to see WHAT caused the reboot EventID 1074/Source = User32.

Comment: Did you verify in the Windows Update history and Windows Update log that Windows Updates was the cause of the reboot?

Comment: Added the GPRESULT and EventID 1074 data to question.

Comment: If there were pending reboots, with warnings popping up from the system tray, someone may have clicked the reboot prompt without thinking, and that click could have caused the reboot outside of your desired schedule. I am not sure if that kind of interaction is logged in `Windowsupdate.log` but you could try looking, maybe under the `AUCLNT` category https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/902093

Comment: That's frankly impossible, @Craig620. Both of these servers are VMs and nobody connected to either in the previous week other than me.